# Mobile devices: Most user friendly way to create "copyable" text field?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a servlet based app that serves content meant to be copied and re-used by users on mobile devices. As of now I'm serving the content (a String) in an input field.

This works fairly good on iOs devices, but rather poorly on Android. Thus I'm wondering if there is a better way to make select and copy easier?

I've tried looking into using jQuery to do the select and copy part, but as far as I can tell this only works using a combination of flash and native languages on their respective platforms. As this app is meant to be compatible on (hopefully) all platforms (W7P as well) this is the least preferable option.

Comment: Why dont you make a button that puts the string into the clipboard?

Comment: That was my initial idea - however I've so far been unable to find an implementation of this that works on all browsers. If you have any workable code that does I would love to see it.

Comment: Hm, I didn't even know that was a problem. Found this, but it basically confirms what you said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript